# disable mobile back button in phonegap[ and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I developing a app using phoneGap and jQueryMobile. For this I am using in app browser. Its work properly except one issue. when I open app it goes to login page. After login I click mobile back button it goes to login page but it should not happen. similarly if I browse multiple pages and want to exit then it moves one by one pages so its not close my app by clicking single back button. 
So to fix this issue i used hashcode in url. Now it disable back button but my jQueryMobile pop not working because its work on hash in url.

Please suggest how to fix this.
Either suggest a method to disable back button without using hash code or open popup if hashcode used.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518531/how-to-get-android-app-to-quit-when-press-back-button-on-index-html-using-phoneg/27519255#27519255

Comment: where i need to add this code in phone gap or in website...

Comment: you have to follow this link if any confusion  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Answer (score 0):

To disable hard backbutton use the following code

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Or you can do page back navigation in `OnBackKeyDown` method as follows

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
   history.go(-1);
   navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

Comment: its not working on my side... I add this in my jQueryMobile site..
please let me know I need to add this in phoneGap or in my site(which is developed in cakephp)..?